# Linked-list based vector

Tags: c++, containers

I was thinking about the downside of using the `std::vector` container, and was wondering if using a chunked linked-list as a back-end might avoid the copy that occurs when the vector extends.

Something like [this](https://docs.google.com/a/polynomic3d.com/file/d/0B2_dEKzRxdQnc0p1QTRZb0tlYjA/edit).

I guess my question is, is this a practical idea and am I right to assume that reading from the container would have similar runtime as the array-based vector, while the "grow" time would be vastly reduced?

Comment: Should be fixed, sorry about that!

Comment: [`std::deque`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/deque/deque/) and its native adaptors, `queue` and `stack`.

Comment: It seems like an application dependant question, but I dont see an application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The run-time (random) access of your solution would be greater than that of the `std::vector`.

In order to access element `N`, you may have to go through many links to get to the appropriate block, then access an element through the block.

The performance of large vectors can be reduced by allocating a larger size up front.

If insert and removal is frequent, perhaps a vector is the wrong data structure.

Answer (score 3):

You could do some experiment using `std::deque`, which just work as your description.